# GO statement behaves differently when called in sql job

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please explain me the behavior of GO statement.
I had given two T-SQl statements

```
truncate table CustomerDetails
GO
truncate table CustomerDetails_Log
GO
```

The table CustomerDetails does **not** exists, even if I truncate the table, it goes to the next statement, but displays in the Message section of SQL server that the "CustomerDetails table does not exist" and proceeds with the next truncation of CustomerDetails_Log.
If I place the same set of SQL statements in a SQL job, it fails at the first level, and does not proceed to next statement.
Can anyone please explain me this behavior, as why does GO behave differently in job and in TSQL places.

Thanks
P.S : I do understand that I have not understood the concept of GO properly, any good links would also be very helpful.

Comment: `GO` is **not** a statement, nor a T-SQL command. It's a **delimiter** used in SQL Server Management Studio to separate "batches" of T-SQL code

Comment: Thanks marc_s, any links to understand GO better

Comment: How about: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx - the SQL Server Books Online is fantastic - just use it!!

Answer (score 1):

To make this work in a SQL job you can wrap each step in TRY/CATCH blocks. This has the added benefit of allowing you to handle/log any problems.

```
BEGIN TRY
    TRUNCATE TABLE CustomerDetails
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Log error
END CATCH
GO

BEGIN TRY
    TRUNCATE TABLE CustomerDetails_Log
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Log error
END CATCH
GO
```